# High performance - converting Objects to Array while sorting keys

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following object:

```
var myObj = {
              "4":{//The key is a number String.
                    id:4,name:aaaa
                  }
              "1":{
                    id:1,name:a
                  }
              "2":{
                    id:2,name:aa
                  }
              "3":{
                    id:3,name:aaa
                  }
            }
```

And i would like to convert it to the following array:

```
var myArr = [{id:1,name:a},{id:2,name:aa},{id:3,name:aaa},{id:4,name:aaaa}]
```

My question is more of a syntax question, can the following pseudo code be done with Javascript:

```
1. Create an array with the size of Object.keys(myObj).length.
2. For each key in myObj
    2.1 set myArr[key] = myObj[key]
```

What would be the fastest way to achieve that?

BTW, it is used in my node.js server and not a browser client.

Comment: Are your id's always consecutive integers, like 1..n?

Comment: Premature optimisation is the root of all evil:-). For this size of object it doesn't really matter how you convert and sort it.

Comment: @hege_hegedus yes, my Id's are.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think any manipulation will do any real performance gain. 
Also, since JavaScript works on "reference to-" approach, the real hit here is to create an array and sort it, since you don't really deep-copy the objects. 
it shouldn't be real performance hit since the array is small in your example.

in this case, prefer clear code over psudo-performant code:

```
var arr = [];
for (var o in myObj){
   arr.push(myObj[o]);
}
arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.id-b.id;
});
```

Comment: In that case, i think that `_.sort(_.values(myObj), 'id');` using Lodash will make more sense. (If the performance hit will not be meaningful anyway) 
Don't you agree?

Comment: well, it depends. for me, I don't do javascript at work every day, but every now and then. consequently,I don't have time to review every utility library exists. I prefare keeping my projects as low with libraries as I can. libraries come and go, but clean javascript stays the same. but use lodash if that is more clear to you

Answer (score 1):

First of all your JSON is not a valid JSON, Use `,` and `""`. To achieve your task use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var myObj = {
              "4":{//The key is a number String.
                    id:4,name:"aaaa"
                  },
              "1":{
                    id:1,name:"a"
                  },
              "2":{
                    id:2,name:"aa"
                  },
              "3":{
                    id:3,name:"aaa"
                  }
            };

var arr = Object.keys(myObj).sort(function(a,b){return +a - +b;}).map(function(x){ return myObj[x]; }); // ES6
document.write(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

For ECMAScript6 Use

```
var arr = Object.keys(myObj).sort().map( x => myObj[x]);
```

Comment: `["120","11","13"].sort()` -> `["11", "120", "13"]`

Comment: @hege_hegedus correct. I already edited it. The first code i posted wont work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just sort the keys:

```js
var myObj = { "4": { id: 4, name: 'aaaa' }, "1": { id: 1, name: 'a' }, "2": { id: 2, name: 'aa' }, "3": { id: 3, name: 'aaa' } },
    result = Object.keys(myObj).map(Number).sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
    }).map(function (k) {
        return myObj[k];
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash:

```
var sortedById = _.sortBy(_.values(myObj), 'id');
```